# Calling external program through Python and passing the output to stdout

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

How can I call an external program which is written in bash script in such a way that the output produced by that script is available in sys.stdout so that I can log the output in a file through python.

For example. I now call them through the following snippet

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    path = module_dir_run+'/run.bat'
else:
    path = module_dir_run+'/run.sh'
if os.path.isfile(path):
    if (splitargs.arg):
        try:
            call([path, splitargs.arg])
        except:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            call([path])
        except:
            pass
else:
    print "Not found : " + path
```

when I store the value of `sys.stdout = file(filename, "w")` it stores whatever which the python outputs, but not what the script outputs.

NOTE: The script which i am trying to run is an interactive script, so after the call has ended, and the control has come back to python, how can i get all what is written in the terminal? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it mandatory to write the output to `stdout`? I would suggest that just write it to a file and then read the file.

Comment: you need to include what `call` is.

Comment: @InbarRose: `subprocess.call` presumably.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but maybe its a function which implements it with some sort of argument or maybe its something else...

Comment: it is required, since if someone calls the function like run modulename > output.txt

Comment: @MartijnPieters the script has interactive features, where user has to interact, will those be recorded as well?

Comment: @SunnyRockzzs: You cannot redirect stdout output *and* interact with a human being; they cannot see the output to interact with the script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so there is no way by which when the script is finished running, and the control comes back to python, it records all which is present in between in the terminal ?

Comment: @SunnyRockzzs: Not and support output redirection, no. You *can* use `PIPE` on `stdout`, print that and write it to a file separately. If you run `python script.py > output.txt` the end-user won't get to see the output interactively.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not doing that, I am using the cmd module for a custom commandline based program, so I start the program with `python run.py` and then in the interface I type `run module_name` which runs the specified function and calls the script ! now I am trying to add a feature like `run module_name > output.log`

Comment: You need to explain your scenario better. I have a feeling that whatever it is you're trying to solve with this elaborate script can be solved with a much simpler implementation. So, please include more details and we'll be able to help better with alternate solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use subprocess.Popen() to run another program from inside a Python script. Example:

```
import subprocess

print "Starting process..."
process = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a"], shell=False)
process.wait()
print "Done"
```

You can redirect the output of process to another file like this:

```
import subprocess

print "Starting process..."
with open("./out.log", "w") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a"], shell=False, stdout=f)
    process.wait()
print "Done"
```

Redirecting stderr is also possible through 'stderr' parameter.

When you have the `sys.stdout` in current script redirected to write to your own file, you can do this to redirect it in your subprocess too:

```
import subprocess
import sys

sys.stdout = open("./out.log", "w")
print "Starting process..."
sys.stdout.flush()
process = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a"], shell=False, stdout=sys.stdout)
process.wait()
print "Done"
```

Comment: the script has interactive features, where user has to interact, will those be recorded as well? If i pass the stdout to a file descriptor befor hand, user cannot interact with the script !

Comment: So you want the output of your subprocess to be visible both on the console and written to the log file? As for the interaction, current stdin is passed implicitly and user will be able to type in commands from keyboard.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want ! but i want the user to interact natively with the script, and when the script has ended, a variable or stdout can store whatever it is writen in the terminal.

Comment: It can be done but it can be a bit of a trouble and you'll have to rely on your subprocess to flush stdout immediatelly when something new appears. Your Python script needs to be able to print to the console, so if you redirected the sys.stdout you will need to keep the original one in a variable somewhere so you can write subprocess's output to it. Then you would need to redirect the subprocess' stdout to a separate file, and in the main process keep reading that file in a loop until process exits. That way you can do anything you want with the output.

Comment: i didn't get you, could you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the outputs of such a call into a variable using e.g.:

```
variable = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ls', 'mydir/'],  # note that the command is split on whitespace
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: the script which i am trying to run has interactive features, where user has to type in their name, etc, will that be recorded too ?

Comment: @SunnyRockzzs so you want to make it callable like ``script.py arg1 arg2``? If I understand correctly, maybe this [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429966/how-to-make-a-python-script-pipeable-in-bash) will take you further

Comment: I think what he means is that the script he's trying to run reads in from stdin. Note his use of the word "interactive". So one needs to redirect stdin back to the shell running the python script.

Answer (score 0):

As Martijn Pieters already states, you'll have to provide an alternative `stdout` for your `call()` call.

There are essentially 2 ways:
* either provide an already opened file (as you have changed your `sys.stdout`, this will probably be fine)
* use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and read and treat the `stdout` yourself. (Not via `subprocess.call()` then, but via the object returned by `subprocess.Popen()`.)

Note that changing `sys.stdout` won't really change your process's stdout from the view of the OS, but instead will order your program to output everything on a non-usual file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use. Particularly because most of the other answers don't understand that you need to redirect your parent shell's stdin to the child process's stdin because the programs/scripts you're calling are "interactive".

[Python and subprocess input piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080906/python-and-subprocess-input-piping)